# Slide-out Menu ListView Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm having trouble with certain parts of code that I can't seem to fix. When I click on Shop1 three items appear in the ListView those being Location, Contact, and Appointment. I would like to know how to go into a different Activity when I select one of those. For instance, if I want to click on Location I want it to take me to a different Layout File. Help would be great!

Here are some photos:

[image: Not Clicked]

Not Clicked

[image]

Clicked

[image]

Click Location to go to different Activity

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private ListView list;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private RibbonMenuView rbmView;
private Button test;
private ListView rbmListView, rbmListView2;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapt, adapter2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** Init our views **/
    rbmView = (RibbonMenuView) findViewById(R.id.ribbonMenuView1);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    /** Calls "hideMenu()" after each click similiar to the Facebook or Google+  application **/
    test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // shows how to hide the menu
            if (rbmView != null)
            {
                rbmView.hideMenu();
            }
        }
    });

    /** This is the most important ListView, updating the main list in the Activity **/
    final String[] items_list = { "Shop1", "Shop2", "Shop3" };
    adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items_list);
    rbmListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rbm_listview);
    if (rbmListView != null)
    {
        rbmListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)
             */
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                switch (position)
                {
                case 0:
                    String[] items = { "Location", "Contact", "Appointment" };
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    String[] items1 = { "Location", "Contact", "Appointment" };
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items1);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    String[] items2 = { "Location", "Contact", "Appointment" };
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items2);
                    break;


                default:
                    String[] itemsd = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsd);
                    break;
                }

                // always update these
                if (list != null)
                {
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setClickable(true);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                            switch ((int)l)
                            {
                                case 0: // Location
                                    //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
                                    //startActivity(intent);
                                    break;
                                case 1: // Contact
                                    //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
                                    //startActivity(intent);
                                    break;
                                case 2: // Appointment
                                    //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
                                    //startActivity(intent);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (rbmView != null)
                {
                    rbmView.hideMenu();
                }
            }
        });
        rbmListView.setAdapter(adapt);
    }

    /** This is the second ListView on the menu **/
    final String[] items_list2 = { "About", "Deals", "Contact Developer", };
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items_list2);
    rbmListView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rbm_listview2);
    if (rbmListView2 != null)
    {
        rbmListView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)
             */
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class));
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DealsCode.class));
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactDev.class));
                        break;
                }
                /*Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, items_list2[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (rbmView != null)*/
                {
                    rbmView.hideMenu();
                }
            }
        });
        rbmListView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
}

/**  Allows users, even API < 5, to use the back button **/
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)
 */
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        // if view is showing, close it
        // all other back button clicks are handled by the phone
        if (rbmView != null)
        {
            if (rbmView.isMenuShowing())
            {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        rbmView.hideMenu();
                    }
                }, 50);
            } 
            else
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }

    return true;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
 */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case R.id.test:
        // toggle our menu
        if (rbmView != null)
        {
            rbmView.toggleMenu();
        }
        break;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    return true;
}
}
```

If anything else is needed please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), activityToStart.class));`

Why are you casting the float which is an ID, to an int? You should just use the int value which is the position.

```
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                            switch (i)
                            {
                                case 0: // Location
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocationActivity.class));

                                    break;
                                case 1: // Contact
;startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ContactActivity.class));

                                    break;
                                case 2: // Appointment
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AppointmentActivity.class));

                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Their is a way to use the float value if you know the "Row Id" of the item clicked.

Comment: I've tried the code with the program but it crashed when I would click either Location, Contact, or Appointment.

Comment: So I ran it again this morning and apparently it ran just fine...don't know if it was an Android Studio issue or something else. But is there a way that I can view different things when I click on the different shops? I'm a bit new to Android so any info that could help me would be awesome

Comment: Since this question is resolved, please post another question. I would be happy to try to help you.

Comment: @Kodi does the above code not let you navigate to another activity?

Comment: it does let me navigate to another activity so the code you provided did work very well what I was wondering was once you click on a different shop if instead of being the same activity it could be different.